# ImportError: cannot import name ForwardHeaderGenerator

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7

I'm trying to install the library KD Soap (Qt-based client-side and server-side SOAP component)  and I get this error :

```
user@server:/path/KDSoap-master/autogen$ python autogen.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autogen.py", line 11, in <module>
    from header import ForwardHeaderGenerator
  File "/path/KDSoap-master/autogen/header.py", line 6, in <module>
    import autogen
  File "/path/KDSoap-master/autogen/autogen.py", line 11, in <module>
    from header import ForwardHeaderGenerator
ImportError: cannot import name ForwardHeaderGenerator
```

I'm running python 2.7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. The library's source may be viewed on [github.com/KDAB/KDSoap](https://github.com/KDAB/KDSoap)

Comment: Don't know, seems like an error in the program itself? While trying to import `ForwardHeaderGenerator`, it tries to import it again which would lead to recursion if Python did not abort... But maybe also just a package or anything similar is missing?

Comment: this is the link to the library on github :  https://github.com/KDAB/KDSoap

I noticed that in the autogen.py we have `from header import ForwardHeaderGenerator` , and in the header itself we have import autogen , is that normal in python ?

Comment: Try editing `.../autogen/header.py` and change the line `import autogen` to `import autogen.policyVersion`. Not sure if that helps, but worth a try. If not, undo the edit.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I did the edit but I still have the same error

Comment: I know, I just tried to reproduce the error in a minimal project. You can't use such circular imports in Python. I'm trying to find a simple fix and will tell you and the authors on github when I found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated, correct answer:

You tried to run the `KDSoap` package in a wrong way. You were not supposed to run any scripts in the `./autogen/` subdirectory manually, according to the package maintainers, but use the `autogen.py` file from the project's root directory:

> you should be running python autogen.py from the top-level source or from a build dir

Source: [GitHub: Comment by the package maintainer](https://github.com/KDAB/KDSoap/pull/66#issuecomment-140106266)

### Wrong answer, because of false assumption of package structure:

> Open `.../autogen/autogen.py` with your preferred text editor.
> We need to edit two lines.

1. Search for line 11:

   ```
   from header import ForwardHeaderGenerator
   ```

   Replace it with:

   ```
   import header
   ```
2. Search for line 99:

   ```
   forwardHeaderGenerator = ForwardHeaderGenerator(
   ```

   Replace it with:

   ```
   forwardHeaderGenerator = header.ForwardHeaderGenerator(
   ```

Those edits should do the trick. After you confirmed it works I will propose the edits to the GitHub repository.

Comment: Please notify me as soon as you checked that it works, because I want to submit the edit to the GitHub repository.

Comment: I will check it  within an hour , because we are in lunch break and I don't have access to the server now,  thank you so much.

Comment: that solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting for the GitHub repository maintainers to merge the pull request and apply my edit.

Comment: @Latyyfa Please see my edit. My first solution would have worked theoretically, but it's not the way the package was meant to get used.